# Create pypi project but cannot import after install from pypi

Tags: python, pypi

I have create a python module, package it, then push to the pypi. All my step is strictly followed this tutorial https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

All the steps works fine, then I install this module in new env (specifically my model is [here](https://test.pypi.org/project/sqlserverconnect/0.0.1/)). However, after install this package, I cannot import this package and it raise an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import sqlserverconnect

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlserverconnect'
```

My pyproject.toml is

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "sqlserverconnect"
#..other fields for metadata
requires-python = ">=3.8"
```

and my project structure is

```
 <root>/
├─ pyproject.toml
└─ src/
  ├─ dbConnector.py
  └─ __init__.py
```

I do not know where the problem comes from and how to solve it. Pls help me??

Comment: Is your module installed in the same environment as the python binary that you use to run your script?

Comment: what does `python -m pip list` show? Is `sqlserverconnect` there?

Comment: Oh. I see from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/johnnyb1509/SQLServerConnector/tree/master/src) that it's probably from the about your folder structure. You don't have any files or folders called `sqlserverconnect`, so you will naturally not be able to import `sqlserverconnect`.

Comment: I guess you might be able to import `src.dbConnector` after installed your package. Or just `dbConnector`, depending how the build is configured.

Comment: Added your pyproject.toml and project structure to the question.

Comment: @NikoPasanen Thank you so much, I understand the problem here

Comment: The project directory structure is not correct from my point of view. As it is now the top-level import package is `src`. But it seems you want to have `sqlserverconnect` as top-level import package. Check again the tutorial and pay close attention to the directory structure. In short your Python code should be in `src/sqlserverconnect` (instead of directly in `src`).